# Rails, Nginx, Puma: Rack app error: RegexpError: failed to allocate memory when uploading large file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, upload, base64, puma

I get error `Rack app error: #<RegexpError: failed to allocate memory: /\A[^%]*(?:%\h\h[^%]*)*\z/>` when I try to upload 25.5mb file. File uploads as base64 encoded data. This error appears in Puma logs.

nginx config:

```
upstream tgmu {
  server unix:///home/railsuser/eis/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 100m;
  root /home/railsuser/eis/current/public;

  server_name xxx;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://tgmu;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

How to fix that?

Comment: p.s. in development all works great

Comment: Seems not related to `nginx`.

Comment: I still think it's something between puma and nginx

Comment: It's not nginx error, seems like nginx handles request correctly to puma, and there goes error. I don't know what `puma` is and can't help there, indeed you may want to check your code, because it's seems not good to check incoming files with regexps.

Comment: How are you uploading files? Use multipart or as request parameter in Base64 encoding?

Comment: As Request parameter In Base64.